# jquery setInterval and setTimeout not working, not looping

Tags: jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I have been having trouble with setTimeout.  It is not looping at all.  I have tried setInterval as well.  I am trying to loop through a deployment script we have to see if we have any code deploying currently.  We want it to run every second.  It checks each line to see if the deployment is in process or if it is done.  I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var file = "secret/dont/tell/anyone";

    setTimeout(function()
    {
        console.log('it was ran!');
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: file,
            success: function(data)
            {
                var lines = data.split("\n"); // Get All Lines

                var currentLine = lines.length;

                currentLine = currentLine - 2;
                currentLine = lines[currentLine];
                currentLine = currentLine.split(":");


                if(currentLine.length == 4)
                {
                    $(document).prop('title', currentLine[0]);
                }

                if(currentLine.length == 5)
                {
                    $(document).prop('title', currentLine[4]);
                }

                for(var i = 0; i < (lines.length - 1); i++)
                {
                    var LineContent = lines[i].split(":"); // Split the current line by delimiter

                    var newLine = $("<div class=\"newLine\">" + LineContent[1] + ": " + LineContent[3] + " (" + LineContent[2] + ")</div>"); // Set up the new div

                    $("body").prepend(newLine); // Prepend the new line so the newest line is at the top
                }

            },
            dataType: 'text'
        });

    }, 1000);

    });
```

Comment: try to remove `dataType`

Comment: does it at least run once?

Comment: The `setTimeout` method isn't supposed to loop, it only calls the callback once. Use `setInterval` instead. You should add `cache: false` to the settings in the ajax call, otherwise you will just see the same response over and over even if the file changes.

Comment: It runs once.  I put the setTimeout inside a function and then I also changed setTimeout to setInterval and it is still not running.

Answer (score 0):

You're not starting the timeout. In order for this to work place it inside a function, then call that function inside the timeout. Like this:

```
    function start() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('it was ran!');
            $.ajax({
                url: file,
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(data) {

                    // ....your other code

                    start(); //starts the loop again
                }
            });

        }, 1000);
    }

   start();//runs the function at load
```